# Re-size the TabelView in iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I'm using the Autosizing mask for `UITableView` so it is working fine with iPhone 5 as well, but I'm doing some frame animation in that controller so the `UITableView` automatically reduces its height.
Not able to understand What is going wrong. I did the autosizing mask programmatically also but doesn't works. I'm stuck here...!

Lots of thanks.

Comment: Share the source code.!!

Answer (score 0):

you should not use **UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin** in autoresizing mask if there is Tab bar bottom toolbar at bottom of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
self.tblRoomList.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.tblRoomList.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Or do like this

[image: Or do like this in xib]

Comment: You are not doing it correct from code, only the last one will be used. To get the same as the image: `self.tblRoomList.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`